# Библиотеки deeppavlov

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Библиотека deeppavlov установлена. В Jupyter Notebook импортирую следующее:

```
from deeppavlov.contrib.skills.similarity_matching_skill import SimilarityMatchingSkill
```

Но, появляется ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deeppavlov.contrib'
```

Как установить модуль contrib?

Comment: Скорее всего пример, откуда вы взяли этот импорт, для более старой версии библиотеки. Попробуйте `from deeppavlov.deprecated.skills.similarity_matching_skill import SimilarityMatchingSkill` - но deprecated намекает на то что это будет скоро выпилено из библиотеки. Поищите более свежий пример. Лучше всего - из [официальной документации](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/), а не с Хабра.

Answer (score 0):

замени contrib на deprecated, то есть 
from deeppavlov.deprecated.skills.similarity_matching_skill import SimilarityMatchingSkill